# How can I encrypt url in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I found a documentation since it is not working with python updated version so I am having this problem. I want to prevent scrapping from my application. There are some api where I am passing sensitive data and my api endpoing is like localhost:8000/api/products/1 but I want this url to be like
localhost:8000/api/products/dheudhuehdeidiwf4yfg4gfy4yf4f4fu4f84j4i this. So which procedure should I follow here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `uuid` as another unique key in your model.

```
import uuid


class Product(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    # other fields ...
```

For the serializers, you'll have to manually set them like:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    uuid = serializers.UUIDField(format="hex", read_only=True)
    # other fields ...

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            "uuid",
            # other fields ...
        ]
```

For the views, I'm assuming you are using `ModelViewSet`, so you can set the uuid as the lookup field like:

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    lookup_field = "uuid"
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about making your sensitive ids urlsafe would be to use `urlsafe_base64_encode` from `django.utils.http`. You could return encrypted ids along with your response to the frontend using:

> uidb64 = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(*model_name*.pk))

the frontend can then persist the encrypted ids and when request are made to your endpoints using those ids, you then decrypt them using `smart_str` from `django.utils.encoding` like this:

> model_name_pk = smart_str(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))

assuming your endpoints looks something like this `'api/an-interesting-route/<uidb64>'`

This approach is more useful with GET endpoints that do not just return the model directly but include some amount of processing of the id before a response is returned.